# publish my project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have little problem to publish my project in C# express edition 2008 (WinForms).

I saw from Google how to do the basic and go to project `property -> publish`

But now in the publish folder that was created under my main project's folder and I have there setup and one more file and folder named application files.

But when I run the setup or the other file I'm getting error:

> cannot start application MYPROJECTNAME from this location because it
>   is already installed from a different location.

I have also in bin-> debug ->app.publish a setup file which works fine until it needs to use a txt file in my project and it says that the txt file can't be found.

Comment: have you checked http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbide/thread/2cf4708f-30e1-487a-8bcf-9c329e1cdd48